# Margin-top not working

Tags: html, css

When I use the margin-left it works. But the margin-top does not work. Anyone know why the on does work and the other doesn't?

Html code

```
<div id="footer"> <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<p class="copyright"> Copyright © </p>
</div> <!-- END FOOTER -->
```

Css

```
#footer {

background-image: url(../website/images/footer.png);
width: 1200px;
height: 100px;

}

p.copyright {

margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 120px;

}
```

Comment: What is above your footer? something that has been floated? positioned? Possible that the floats havent been cleared?

Comment: Here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qyUMC/. Can you give more code

Comment: @Enve It doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/nFJgV/

Comment: your p tag default having margins, instead use margin-top:20 or something else for the top may be it will work

Comment: @Enve's Example works, actually his own markup works perfectly, unless and untill he means that even the parent div is shifted below

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's a fair bet that he wants the margin to apply inside the div. Otherwise he wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's called margin collapse. It happens when one block element is the child of another block element. here are a couple of methods to tackle the problem.

1-   Add a border to the element

2-   Add 1px of padding

3-   change the position property. Margins of absolutely and relatively positioned boxes don’t collapse.

I've recently written a blog post about that to learn more refer [here](http://www.eloux.com/css-margin-top-problem/)

Comment: More info about margin collapse https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/

Answer (score 0):

try out [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/nFJgV/2/)

```
#footer {
    background-image: url(../website/images/footer.png);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
}

p.copyright {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

```
  #footer {
    background-image: url(../website/images/footer.png);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden; // add overflow
  }
    
  p.copyright {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
```